# How to change the color of CircularProgress bar

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-material, mean-stack

I am trying to change the color of circular progress bar provided by AngularMaterial. I have tried changing its color to white using css but it's not working and the color of the progress bar stays BLUE. What am I doing wrong?

```
.centeredPLEASE_WAIT {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
}


.my-circular-progress {
  color: white;
  border-right: #ddd;
  border-left: #ddd;
  border-top: #ddd;
  border-bottom: #ddd;
  background-color: red;
}

            <div class="centeredPLEASE_WAIT">
                <md-progress-circular class="my-circular-progress" md-mode="indeterminate"></md-progress-circular>
            </div>
```

Comment: can u give working url or js fiddle in this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you probably know you can change progress bar color by adding angular material class (`md-warn md-accent` etc.) as it is shown in their demo: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/progressCircular

But if you want to change it manually, you have to change svg image inside `md-progress-circular` element. You can do this using this selector:

```
md-progress-circular svg path { stroke: green; }
```

Comment: How do I assign it to a specific md-progress-circular?

Comment: Instead of 'md-progress-circular' use class or id of your specific md-progress-circular : )

Comment: for example: `.my-circular-progress svg path { stroke: green; }`

Answer (score 0):

you will need to update CSS for below class as i have written below. This will make color kind of dark pink.

```
md-progress-circular.md-default-theme path, md-progress-circular path {
stroke:rgb(150,90,102);
}
```

you can change RGB as per your need.